# Url features extraction in java

Tags: java

I need to extract features like redirect length i.e no of redirects of an URL. Can anyone suggest a code in java.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
    "http://nyti.ms/hfqgE4").openConnection();
con.connect();
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);
```

This gives me the redireccted path. I need to calculate number of redirects from original URL till the landing URL.

Comment: Wouldn't simply iterating over that, taking the redirect result each time until redirection no longer occurs, let you step through the redirections? Loop and counter...

Comment: I need to count the number of redirects till the url leads thelanding page. say url xxx redirects to yyy then the final landing page is zzz. in tis case count is 1. could anyone suggest code in java to find out.

Comment: Thanks @keshlam got wat u said. its working.